# Terminal: Adding logic to 'find' directories containing either [criteria A] or [criteria B]

Tags: terminal, bash, search

I have inherited a vast media archive without a unifying organizational scheme. Its contents date back at least 10 years. I have been asked to find a needle in this hay stack, and I have some guesses as to that needle's name. But I don't know its name for certain. I want to use a single `find` command in the Terminal to search for alternate names. And I want to include a second set: possible file extensions. In pseudocode, here's what I mean: `find [in a given directory] [files and folders whose name matches (*guess1* OR *guess2*) AND whose name matches (*.extension1 OR *.extension2)]`. How should I express this in the Terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using ls and grep with regular expressions

```
ls | grep -E "(guess1|guess2)(\.extension1|\.extension2)"
```

Or if you need to recursively look into folders:

```
ls -R | grep -E "(guess1|guess2)(\.extension1|\.extension2)"
```

Comment: Obligatory note: there are [downsides to parsing ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: I second the admonition from @grgarside that parsing the output of `ls` is a poor approach to choose in general, even though it may happen to do the job for you.

Answer (score 2):

Use the command

```
find /dir/to/search \( -iname '*guess1*' -o -iname '*guess2*' \) \
                    \( -iname '*.extension1' -o -iname '*.extension2' \)
```

[`find`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html) works recursively.  Use `-maxdepth 1` to make it non-recursive.

`-iname` does a case-insensitive filename match.

Arguments are implicitly joined by AND, but you can use `-o` to make it OR.  Parentheses have to be escaped with a backslash to protect them from the shell.

(It could be written all on one line; here I've broken the lines using <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>return</kbd> for readability.)

Answer (score 1):

`find` is slow. `grep` and other text search tools are much faster. Unless you think you're going to find the needle in the haystack with the first shot, you're probably better off doing a `find` into a temporary file, e.g. `find . -print > /tmp/find.out`, and then searching in that file for file names that meet your search criteria.

Answer (score 1):

If the volume is indexed by Spotlight, then use [`mdfind`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/SpotlightQuery/Concepts/QueryFormat.html) for fastest results.

```
mdfind -onlyin /dir/to/search '(kMDItemFSName==*guess1* || kMDItemFSName==*guess2*)' \
                     '&& (kMDItemFSName=*.extension1 || kMDItemFSName=*.extension2)'
```